# Nginx configuration location

Tags: nginx

I have the following Nginx configuration file...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
    location = /index.html {
            root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
            index index.html;
    }

    location / {
            root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
            index index.html;
    }

    location /common/ {
            root /etc/nginx/html/common;
    }
}
```

And the folder structure is like so...

html\app1

html\common

When I try to browse...

http://localhost/ > Works

http://localhsot/index.html > Works

http://localhost/common/somefile.txt > Doesn't work

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `alias` instead of `root`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;

  location / {
    root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
    index index.html;
  }

  location /common {
    alias /etc/nginx/html/common;
  }
}
```

If you use `root` in `common` the `127.0.0.1/common/somefile.txt` will try `/etc/nginx/html/common/common/somefile.txt` (notice the two `common`). If you check `nginx`'s logs you can see it.

Comment: Thanks uzsolt. A quick question... when you say Nginx logs, do you mean access logs? In my access logs, I am able to see only the /common path. Is there any field that I can enable which will show the root path as well?

Answer (score 1):

I am adding my own answer since I finally got it working. Posting it here, so it might help others...

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
location = /index.html {
        root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
        index index.html;
}

location / {
        root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
        index index.html;
}

location ^~ /common/ {
        root /etc/nginx/html;
}
}
```

Basically, the way Nginx was trying was /etc/nginx/html/common/common. Removing the common from root worked. Also found that http://localhost:8888/common/ needed to have a trailing /.

Comment: You don't need `location = /index.html` because the `location /` expression contains it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it firstly match the `location /`. You can do it like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
    location = /index.html {
            root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
            index index.html;
    }

    location / {
            root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
            index index.html;
    }

    location ^~ /common/ {
            root /etc/nginx/html/common;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT：**
Yeah. It seems some complicated.  You can do it like this:
First, you need create a new server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name common.com;   # A virtual host
    root /etc/nginx/html/common;
}
```

Then, you need modify the config above like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
    location = /index.html {
            root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
            index index.html;
    }

    location / {
            root /etc/nginx/html/app1;
            index index.html;
    }

    location ^~ /common/ {
             rewrite ^/common(/.*)$  $1  break; # rewrite the /common/
             proxy_set_header Host common.com;  # it will requests common.com which the server of 127.0.0.1. then will match the above server.
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your configuration, but still the same error.

Comment: I think your solution below will pollute the html directory. It seems not a  good way.

Comment: Well, it is just for my own understanding and simplification of the issue that I am facing.